# React useState delayed when updating nested object

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to update an array within my state object by pushing in an item to the array as soon as you click on a button. I'm taking a copy of state, updating that copy and setting the state to that copy. The expectation is that as soon as the item gets pushed in, a new select element is added to the page as it maps through that array and adds selects. It only does this after the second click though. After inspecting with React dev tools, the array isn't updated on first click which makes me think the component isn't reloading. Not sure why as I'm updating state.

The button used to trigger the function:

```
<Col xl={6}>
              
  <button onClick={(e) => renderSelects(e)}>Add</button>
                
</Col>
```

The function itself:

```
const renderSelects = (e: any) => {

        e.persist();
        let id = userData.languages.length + 1;
        let language = new Language(id, "Please select an option");
        let data: any = userData;
        data.languages = [...data.languages, language];
        setUserData(data);
}
```

The select elements:

```
<Row>
   {
      userData.languages.map((language: Language, key: any) => {

          return (
                <Col xl={6} key={key}>
                       <Form.Group controlId="formGroupName">
                            <Form.Label>Native in</Form.Label>
                                   <Select
                                        authid={`language${key}`}
                                         type="text"
                                         required
                                         errortext="Please select an option."
                                         inputchange={inputChangeHandler}
                                         languages={allLanguages}
                                         userlanguages={userData.languages}
                                         initialvalue={language.name} />
                        </Form.Group>
                 </Col>)
         })
    }
</Row>
```

Any advice on how I can achieve this update instantly without the delay?

Comment: You are mutating state, does `let data: any = {...userData};` work?

Comment: It did indeed, thank you!!